# Load more than one database for a single project

Tags: git, ddev

Does anyone know if there a way I can have more than one db associated with a single Ddev project?

I'm working on a version-controlled project which uses [Ddev](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/) as the hosting environment. I want to run an upgrade on a CMS in my project and have created a new branch for the purpose and would like to create a separate database for the upgrade too so that when I switch between branches it switches database too.

But it seems that Ddev only allows one db to be linked to a project at one time.

This [Github issue](https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/939) suggests creating a separate Ddev project for each Git branch but because everything in my repos also gets deployed to branches on the server, they'd end up with Ddev config files that they don't need, so I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bet, `ddev import-db` takes a `--database`  argument, so you can `ddev import-db --file=/path/to/import.sql.gz --database=myseconddb` and it will automatically create a new database called "myseconddb".

This is also covered in the [ddev FAQ](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/faq/) under "Can I use additional databases".

There's also a full discussion of all the ways you can manage databases in the article [DDEV Database Management](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/usage/database-management/)

Comment: Thanks. I did do a search of the docs but the content on the FAQ page never came up.

Answer (score 0):

I wish among all the topics I found on "ddev extra database" there was "one" that answered how to create an additional "empty" database not as an import from a dump file... i mean, sure, you can create an empty dump and import that as a secondary database... but that's not the way we really want to deal with, is it?

After some searching, trial and error, here's what I came up with this in config.yaml:

```
hooks:
  post-start:
    - exec: mysql -uroot -proot -hdb -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db2; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db2.* TO 'db'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'db';"
```

What I am wondering is why this does not work with "ddev exec"

```
ddev exec mysql -uroot -proot -hdb -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db2; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db2.* TO 'db'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'db';"
```

Creation works with "ddev mysql" (but not the PRIVILEGES..., so access prohibited)

```
ddev mysql -uroot -proot -hdb -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db3; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db3.* TO 'db'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'db';"
```

after all, i can go with the hook